# R - Subset based on conditions for paired data

Tags: r, merge, subset

I am trying to subset **paired** data based on conditions.
The *pair* comprises two individuals observed during 2 days.

The main data of my sample are : 
`'hldid', 'cid', 'pid', 'diary', 'sex', 'day', 'main1'`.

`'hldid'` refers to the paired data identifier,

`'cid'` is the paired data-day identifier

`'pid'` the personal identifier
`'diary'` the diary (each individuals must have filled 2 diaries) 
`'sex' 'day' 'main1'` refer to the sex, day and the activities observed.

What I would like to do is to subset the data based on 2 conditions :

1. The data must be *paired* meaning that `hldid` must be of 2 individuals. 
   Each pair should be made of a man and a woman.
2. Individuals must have filled 2 `diary`. So 4 diary by `hldid`

The only way I found to do this is to do the following :

Separate by sex

```
M = filter(dtaSimple, sex == 1)
W = filter(dtaSimple, sex == 2)
```

Merge by paired-day identifier

```
dtaSimple_c = merge(M, W, by = 'cid', suffixes = c('_m', '_w'))
```

Then I'll get

```
     cid hldid_m  pid_m diary_m sex_m day_m main1_m hldid_w  pid_w diary_w sex_w day_w main1_w
 1 1250_1    1250 1250_2       1     1     1       0    1250 1250_1       1     2     1       0
 2 1250_2    1250 1250_2       2     1     3       0    1250 1250_1       2     2     3       0
 3 1294_1    1294 1294_2       1     1     6       0    1294 1294_1       1     2     6       0
 4 1294_2    1294 1294_2       2     1     1       0    1294 1294_1       2     2     1       0
```

I think this is not really satisfactory. 
Each line refers to the first diary of each `hldid` and each column refes to either the man or the women of the `pair`.

I would like to keep the original data structure of 1 line one individual and one day.

```
   hldid    cid    pid diary sex day main1
1   1250 1250_1 1250_1     1   2   1     0
2   1250 1250_2 1250_1     2   2   3     0
3   1250 1250_1 1250_2     1   1   1     0
4   1250 1250_2 1250_2     2   1   3     0
 .....
```

The data:

```
dtaSimple = structure(
   list(
       hldid = c(1250, 1250, 1250, 1250, 1294, 1294, 1294, 1294, 1352, 1352), 
       cid = c("1250_1", "1250_2", "1250_1", "1250_2", "1294_1",  "1294_2", "1294_1", "1294_2", "1352_1", "1352_2"), 
       pid = c("1250_1", "1250_1", "1250_2", "1250_2", "1294_1", "1294_1", "1294_2", "1294_2", "1352_1", "1352_1"), 
       diary = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), 
       sex = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), 
       day = c(1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 3L), 
       main1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), 
   .Names = c("hldid", "cid", "pid", "diary", "sex", "day", "main1"), 
   row.names = c(NA, 10L), 
   class = "data.frame"
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like you need to filter by a grouping variable.  As far as I understand it, for each `hldid` you want to make sure there are 2 distinct values for `sex` and 4 observations total.

You could use `filter` and `group_by` from **dplyr**:

```
library(dplyr)

dtaSimple %>% 
    group_by(hldid) %>%
    filter(n_distinct(sex) == 2, n() >= 4)

  hldid    cid    pid diary sex day main1
1  1250 1250_1 1250_1     1   2   1     0
2  1250 1250_2 1250_1     2   2   3     0
3  1250 1250_1 1250_2     1   1   1     0
4  1250 1250_2 1250_2     2   1   3     0
5  1294 1294_1 1294_1     1   2   6     0
6  1294 1294_2 1294_1     2   2   1     0
7  1294 1294_1 1294_2     1   1   6     0
8  1294 1294_2 1294_2     2   1   1     0
```

Change the dataset so one `hldid` doesn't have 4 observations to test more thoroughly:

```
dtaSimple2 = dtaSimple[-4,]

dtaSimple2 %>% 
    group_by(hldid) %>%
    filter(n_distinct(sex) == 2, n() >= 4)

  hldid    cid    pid diary sex day main1
1  1294 1294_1 1294_1     1   2   6     0
2  1294 1294_2 1294_1     2   2   1     0
3  1294 1294_1 1294_2     1   1   6     0
4  1294 1294_2 1294_2     2   1   1     0
```

If each `sex` must have 2 diary entries and one sex could have 1 entry and the other could have 3 entries you'll need a slightly different strategy.  Maybe just make sure you have more than 2 observations for each `sex` for each `id`?

```
dtaSimple %>% 
    group_by(hldid) %>%
    filter(sum(sex == 1) >= 2, sum(sex == 2) >= 2)
```

Comment: ok, just when I get the hang of `ddply` I get introduced to dplyr filtering. R is so cool!

Answer (score 1):

In the `plyr` library there is a function `ddply` which is good for quick groupings and tabulation by combinations of column values. Considering you want very specific counts for groupings, I like `ddply` for this. This chains two `ddply()` functions together to ultimately filter out the individuals based on:
1) they don't have two diary values

```
# calculate the number of diaries by pid (we are looking for exactly two):
diaryByPid <- ddply(dtaSimple,c("pid"),function(x){ length(unique(x$diary))})

# the valid pids have exactly two unique diary values
validPid <- diaryByPid$pid[which(diaryByPid[,2]==2)]

# now subset the original dtaSimple to retain only those matched above
dtaSub <- dtaSimple[which(dtaSimple$pid %in% validPid),]
```

We excluded records for which there were not two unique diary values by pid. Now we need to pair them up with their corresponding `cid` values and make sure that both sexes are represented:

```
# ddply to group by cid and count the number of unique values of $sex column
sexByCid <- ddply(dtaSub,c("cid"),function(x){ length(unique(x$sex))})

# retain the cids for which we have two unique sexes
validCid <- sexByCid$cid[which(sexByCid[,2]==2)]

# subset the previously subsetted dtaSub to remove records without gender matches.
dtaSub2 <- dtaSub[which(dtaSub$cid %in% validCid),]
```

Since we have only removed rows from the original structure, it remains in the same format:

```
head(dtaSub2)
  hldid    cid    pid diary sex day main1
1  1250 1250_1 1250_1     1   2   1     0
2  1250 1250_2 1250_1     2   2   3     0
3  1250 1250_1 1250_2     1   1   1     0
4  1250 1250_2 1250_2     2   1   3     0
5  1294 1294_1 1294_1     1   2   6     0
6  1294 1294_2 1294_1     2   2   1     0
7  1294 1294_1 1294_2     1   1   6     0
8  1294 1294_2 1294_2     2   1   1     0
```